# How to set log file with mongo java driver?

Tags: java, mongodb, logging, mongo-java-driver

I have a java program who make insert in my database and print some logs.

I use :

```
import com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.Logger;
import com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.Loggers;

static Logger logger = Loggers.getLogger("JULLogger");
```

I would like to know how to configure a config-properties log for select a file for the log.
Actually, my log is just print on my terminal.

Thanks in advance

Comment: These classes are for internal use and you are discouraged from using these . You should use your usual Java logging framework console appender

Comment: Ok, thanks ^^ I will do like this

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a file "monog.cfg" in mongodb folder and insert following content

**systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: c:\mongodb\data\log\mongod.log
storage:
    dbPath: c:\mongodb\data\db**

Note: Foldernames and path can be change.

2. From terminal/cmd

*"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongod.exe" --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\mongod.cfg" --install*

That's it.
mongod.log file contains terminal logs 
Details can be seen [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)